How can i run npm and gulp from a relative path in windows?
I have npm and gulp installed on windows 11.  Where are they files located so i can run using a relative path ?
for example instead of running from the command line just
           npm install

I want to run
          c:\program files\npm\npm.exe install

Is this possible , if so how can i do it ?
